# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable python web scraping

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I am trying to scrape information from a website that is written in html. Attached is my code below:

```
#Import packages
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import csv   


#For loop to scrape details of power plants
lst=[]
for i in range(1,46624):
     pid=str(i)
     url="http://www.globalenergyobservatory.com/form.php?pid=" + pid
     page=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
     soup=BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')

     #Distinguish power plants to different types of primary fuel
     types=soup.find(id="Type")
     power_types=types["value"]


     #No of units of power plant
     unit=soup.find(id="Abstract_Block")
     unit_breakdown_describe=unit.get_text()

     #Name of power plant
     name=soup.find(id="Name")
     name_value=name["value"]

     #Status of power plant
     status1=soup.find(id="Status_of_Plant_enumfield_itf")
     status2=status1.find(selected="selected") 
     status=status2["value"]

     #Latitude & longitude of power plant
     lat=soup.find(id="Latitude_Start")
     latitude=lat["value"]
     long=soup.find(id="Longitude_Start")
     longitude=long["value"]

     #Capacity of power plant
     cap=soup.find(id="Design_Capacity_(MWe)_nbr") 
     capacity=cap["value"]

lst.append([name_value,status,power_types,capacity,latitude,longitude,unit_breakdown_describe])
df=pd.DataFrame(lst)    #Convert to dataframe for storage
df.columns=['Name','Status','Type_of_power_plant','Capacity','Latitude','Longitude','no_of_units'] 

#Convert to csv file
df.to_csv('power.csv',sep='\t')
```

I am trying to scrape the information and put into a `DataFrame` to be converted to a `csv` file. Although I did not encounter any errors when  trying to run the respective values (e.g, print(capacity)), the error appeared when I try to convert to a `csv` file. I understand there are similar threads with regards to this but I hope any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like an issue with the way your're trying to bind data. Works fine when I tried it with 2 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

The only error I see is that the line where you add the data to the list is not correctly indented
It should be inside the loop, and there the csv will be correctly filled in

```
lst=[]
for i in range(1,46624):

    # Your code here

    #Capacity of power plant
    cap=soup.find(id="Design_Capacity_(MWe)_nbr") 
    capacity=cap["value"]

    lst.append([name_value,status,power_types,capacity,latitude,longitude,unit_breakdown_describe])
```